# CXF3.1-java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

Hi the following is my code and i am new CXF. this gives error. how to resolve this?

**My code:-**

```
String username = "myusername";
    String password = "myPassword";

    String usernameAndPassword = username + ":" + password;
    String authorizationHeaderName = "Authorization";
    String authorizationHeaderValue = "Basic " + java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( usernameAndPassword.getBytes() );

    // Build the form for a post request
    MultivaluedMap&lt; String, String&gt; formParameters = new MultivaluedHashMap();
    formParameters.add( "field1", "fieldValue1" );
    formParameters.add( "field2", "fieldValue2" );

    // Perform a post request
    String restResource = "https://restserver:8080/app-name/rest-api/";
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    Response res = client.target( restResource )
        .path( "login" ) // API Module Path
        .request( "application/json" ) // Expected response mime type
        .header( authorizationHeaderName, authorizationHeaderValue ) // The basic authentication header goes here
        .post( Entity.form( formParameters ) );
```

**The following is the error:-**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.path(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.ClientImpl$WebTargetImpl.path(ClientImpl.java:364)
at org.ymd.CxfClient.main(CxfClient.java:35)
```

**My dependencies:-**

- cxf-rt-rs-client-3.1.7.jar
- cxf-rt-transports-http-hc-3.1.7.jar
- cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.1.2.jar
- cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.7.jar
- cxf-core-3.1.7.jar
- cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.7.jar
- javax.persistence-2.1.1.jar 
  -cxf-api-2.7.18.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar

Comment: It  seems odd that all of your jars are version 3.1.7, except for `cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.1.2.jar`, which is 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. it is because of version conflict. When i use maven for getting dependencies everything got resolved.